# Can't parse an HTML element from web page by loop in, after some time parsing in java

Tags: java, loops, parsing, exception, server

I receive different exceptions after some iteration in runtime when I try to parse page and get the same element every 10 seconds.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
```

Or EOFexception, SocketException, UnknownExceptiin.
In addition I am using maven for project and Jsoup for parsing, and I have last version of JDK (however I don't think it'll help). Here is my code.

```
package com.download;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Download
{
    public static void download() throws IOException,InterruptedException
    {
      for(int i=0;i<120;i++)
      {
        System.out.println(Parser.parse());  
        Thread.sleep(10000);
      }
    }
}

public class Parser
{
  public static String parse( ) throws IOException
  {
      String data=parseElement();
      String time=getDate();

      return data+" "+time;
  }

  private static String parseElement() throws IOException
  {
      String url = "https://www.example.com/domain-has-changed-here";
      Document page = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(0).get();

      return page.getElementById("last_last").text();
  }

  private static String getDate() throws IOException
  {
      LocalTime myDateObj = LocalTime.now();
      DateTimeFormatter myFormatObj = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
      String time = myDateObj.format(myFormatObj);

      return time;
    }
}
```

Have any Ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your code succeed for non-SSL URLs?

Comment: How can I check that?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the site that detected you as spam, to reduce this risk I recommend you customize your connection depending on the site, here is an example of customization:

```java
Connection connection = Jsoup.connect("https://www.example.com/domain-has-changed-here");
connection.userAgent("Mozilla");
connection.timeout(5000);
connection.cookie("cookiename", "val234");
connection.cookie("cookiename", "val234");
connection.referrer("http://google.com");
connection.header("headersecurity", "xyz123");
Document docCustomConn = connection.get();
```